# How to break from exception treatment

Tags: python, exception

From a list of exception treatment (but without covering each possible exception) how can I end (break) before reaching the generic treatment?

See below the point where I would like to "break" and just return from function or continue over the generic treatment:

```
try:
    # do_f
except (ex1,ex2,ex3) as e:
    # treat exception
except special_exception as e:
    # treat this one
    # do not continue to generic treatment/break <---
except Exception as e:
    # generic treatment
```

Comment: If you never want to enter the generic treatment, why is it there in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `try` statement, only the first matching `except` clause will be executed.

All other `except` clauses will not be executed and you don't need to "break".

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement